# How to remove more rows?

Tags: php

I created a class that extends pdo functionality, in this class I have created a `delete` function like this:

```
public function delete($table, $where, $limit = 1)
{
    return $this->exec("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $where LIMIT $limit");
}
```

for use it, simply:

```
public function deleteData()
{
    $id = 13;
    $name = "Test";

    $where = "`id` = '{$id}' AND name = '{$name}'";
    $this->db->delete('wine', $where);
}
```

but if I want pass more rows to delete I should I do?

Comment: Why are you limiting?

Comment: Use `$this->db->delete('wine', $where, 99);`? Or any other number instead of 99.

Comment: So simply change the limiter?

Comment: assuming id is really id - then nothing will help. you first need to "not use" id field in your query if you want to delete records with all name. Then you also need to remove limit as said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public function delete($table, array $binds)
{
    $whereStatements = [];
    foreach ($binds as $field => &$value) {
        $whereStatements[] = " $field " . (is_array($value) ? "IN (:$field)" : "= :$field");
        $value = is_array($value) ? implode(',', $value) : $value;
    }

    $where = 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $whereStatements);

    $stmt = $this->prepare("DELETE FROM $table $where");
    $stmt->execute($binds);

    // return how many records were deleted
    return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

usage:

```
$rowsCount = $this->db->delete('MY_TABLE', array(
    'id' => array(1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7),
    'name' => 'myName'
));

echo "I just deleted $rowsCount entries";
```

Please note that this code is not tested.

Comment: Good solution but your code only remove one row. Following your example if I have three id to remove the code only will remove one row as the first id that match with the `where` clause. Maybe the `execute` should be inserted in the iteration? IDK

Comment: It depends on the name field... y

Comment: You must assure you have the same name set for all ids you want to delete

Comment: Verify which is the resulted query which is executed.. I just verified on my local pc and the query `delete from wine where id in (1, 3) and name = 'wine'` it's ok.. I think is another issue here.. it would be better to give us your table structure and some data example

Answer (score 1):

Write your code as below:-

```
public function delete($table, $ids) // No need to set limit
{
    return $this->exec("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id IN($ids)");
}

public function deleteData()
{
    $id1 = 13;  
    $id2 = 14;   
    // Id(PK) is enough for "delete" query
    $this->db->delete('wine', "$id1,$id2");
}

OR

public function deleteData()
{
  $idsArr = ['13','14'];   
  $ids = implode(',',$idsArr);
  // Id(PK) is enough for "delete" query
  $this->db->delete('wine', "$ids");
}
```

Hope it will help you :)